# How can I display the output of this set of codes?

Tags: java

I am wondering how to display the output of this set of codes. I can't seem to get it. It says that I need to create a main method but I don't know how. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class DoWhileSquare {
public int height = 5;
public int width = 5;

public void displaySquare(){
    int x = 0;
    int y;
    while (x < height) {
    y = 0;

        while (y < width) { 
        System.out.println("@");
        y ++;
        } 
    System.out.println();
    x++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Javascript != Java

Comment: Vince Viloria - You need to write a class with `main` method --> instantiate this class there and call any member of this class as per need. Alternatively, you can define the `main` method inside this class itself. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your code is already displaying something, the `@` repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add main method, which the JVM will call when you start the program.
Add this to your class:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    new DoWhileSquare().displaySquare();
}
```